# Web Deploy Command Line Logs in Event Logs (Updated / Inserted / Deleted Files) in event logs

Tags: iis, logging, web-deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

How do I configure Web Deploy Command Line to Force Log every activity in Event Log of Source / Destination / Remote Server.

Please mention any other suggestions you might have for Logging of Web Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can log the activities to the event log, but what you can do is use the `-xml` parameter to output the changes in XML format. You could then use this to log to the event log via a Powershell script, for example.